# Randomly replacing data points in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, random

I'm writing a KNN means approximation program for interpreting microarray data (in real situations, it often comes with errors [EDIT: IN FORM OF MISSING DATA IN SOME POINTS]), and I want to train some code on a (perfect) data set I've got.  Right now, I've organised my data like this:

```
def read(data):
random.seed(2347)
with open("..data.csv") as f: 
    realdata = {"probeID": [], "GeneID": [], "Signal_P/2a-1": [], "Signal_P/2a-2": [], "Signal_P/2a-3": [], "Signal_P/4a-1": [], "Signal_P/4a-2": [], "Signal_P/4a-3": [], "Signal_P/8a-1": [], "Signal_P/8a-2": [], "Signal_P/8a-3": []} #Defining the matrix. Remember to add deletion probability!
    lines = f.readline()
while lines:   
    if lines[0:2] == "Pr": #Skipping the header
        lines = f.readline()
        continue
    line = lines.split("\t") #Separating dis shit, so we can get everything into lists
    data["probeID"].append (line[0])
    data["GeneID"].append (line[1])
    data["Signal_P/2a-1"].append (float(line[2]))
    data["Signal_P/2a-2"].append (float(line[3]))
    data["Signal_P/2a-3"].append (float(line[4]))
    data["Signal_P/4a-1"].append (float(line[5]))
    data["Signal_P/4a-3"].append (float(line[6]))
    data["Signal_P/8a-1"].append (float(line[7]))
    data["Signal_P/8a-2"].append (float(line[8]))
    data["Signal_P/8a-3"].append (float(line[9]))
    lines = f.readline()
    simdata = realdata
```

So I've got simdata equal to realdata, but I want simdata to be equal to realdata, but with a small (say 0,1 or 0,01%) error rate in the floats. My first idea was to assign a random variable between 0 and 999 for every float and then doing an if function, so it would be something like:

```
for point in simdata: #or, I guess, I could do all the simdata.data["Signal_blablabla"]s
    temp = random.random(0, 999)
    if temp = 0:
        point = None
```

This, however, seems intuitively like a really inefficient way to do it, and I'm not even sure if it would work. Is there a better way? I'm pretty new to programming, so if I'm reading my data in a stupid way I'd appreciate corrections there as well.

This does seem like a fairly obvious question, but I can't figure out how to do it efficiently and I couldn't find anyone else asking about it. Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Python has a csv that covers some corner cases (like quoted columns, CR/LF and/or commas in a column, etc.)

Comment: Do not worry about efficiency now, and specially don't worry about efficiency for ad hoc things like generating testing data. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Do you want *every 1000 samples to contain an error*, or *the total error should be 0.1%*, i.e. all samples can contain small errors?

Comment: Hannes: I want one out of 1000 data points to be deleted. I.e. your first option, if I'm parsing correctly.

Paulo: I wouldn't care too much about optimisation, but each of those lists is fairly long, and I've only got a dinky laptop to actually do my code on.

Comment: an impotent comment you said `So I've got simdata equal to realdata`, well you acutally don't...., the code `simdata = realdata` doesn't assign `simdata` with `realdata` content it actually creates a reference....

Comment: I guess your `data` variable is instead a reference to `realdata` otherwise `realdata` will be always "empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of looping along all the data, you may "delete" only the ones referred by a random index.

```
for l in range(0, int(len(data) / 1000)):  # if you have 3000 probes you need 3 "gaps"
    t = int(random.random(0, len(data)))  # let's retrieve a random index for each gap
    data["Signal_P/2a-1"][t] = None  # and let's empty it.
    data["Signal_P/2a-2"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/2a-3"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/4a-1"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/4a-3"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/8a-1"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/8a-2"][t] = None
    data["Signal_P/8a-3"][t] = None
```

Comment: OK, so if I understand it right what you've done here is assign a number to each data point, randomise the order and then turn every thousandth point into "none". Is there an easy way to reorganise the data afterwards, do you know? I'm sorry about being so obtuse, but I do need to use it for a KNN approximation, which means that the lists have to be in the same order. Is there something similar to R, where you can straight out order one vector by another, do you know?

Comment: No the above code picks one or more random member of the data and sets it to None.

Comment: you do not need to re-organize data, my code works with your code without changes (except correcting variable names --se my comment above). Just add it at the end of the code you show us. And no, it not turn off every thousandth. It just checks how many "gaps" do you need (if you have 3245 rows you need 3 gaps), and it empties that exact number of rows from random positions.